# How do I add a row to an array using a for loop in python?

Tags: python, arrays, list, numpy

I have this equation that will produce an array of length 3000:

```
dRcs_Stokes=((112*((math.pi)**4))/15)*(((gj)*planck*c*B0*((nu0+i_dnu_Stokes)**4)*gammaSquared)/(((2*I+1)**2)*kb*T))*(i_Xj_Stokes*(math.exp(((-i_Erot)/(kb*T)))))
```

However, for each iteration inside my for loop, I want to add a new row of length 3000 of newly calculated values to my array. Thus, I should get a 30X3000 array when the for loop is over. How will I do this in python? I keep getting "**only length-1 arrays can be converted to Python scalars**" error. Here are my attemps:

```
dnu_Stokes=np.array([])
Erot= np.array([])
Xj_Stokes=np.array([])
dRcs_Stokes=np.array([])
anti_dnu_Stokes=np.array([])
anti_Xj_Stokes=np.array([])
anti_dRcs_Stokes=np.array([])

for i in range(1,30):
    i_dRcs_Stokes[i-1,:]=((112*((math.pi)**4))/15)*(((gj)*planck*c*B0*((nu0+i_dnu_Stokes)**4)*gammaSquared)/(((2*I+1)**2)*kb*T))*(i_Xj_Stokes*(math.exp(((-i_Erot)/(kb*T)))))
```

Comment: Please provide a [mcve], as well as the entire error output.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `np.append` and `np.stack` to do your loop in numpy, but DO NOT do it. Use lists to construct/append and outside the loop, convert your list to array:

```
i_dRcs_Stokes = []
for i in range(1,30):
    i_dRcs_Stokes.append(((112*((math.pi)**4))/15)*(((gj)*planck*c*B0*((nu0+i_dnu_Stokes)**4)*gammaSquared)/(((2*I+1)**2)*kb*T))*(i_Xj_Stokes*(math.exp(((-i_Erot)/(kb*T))))))
i_dRcs_Stokes = np.array(i_dRcs_Stokes)
```

Also, `range(1,30)` will create a sequence of `[1,2,..,29]`, and your array will be of shape `(29,3000)`. Use range(30) in the code above to achieve shape `(30,3000)`.

Comment: I still get error "only length-1 arrays can be converted to Python scalars".

Comment: docs_Stokes produces an array of values instead of on single value.

Comment: @Jake Please post the full stack of error so we can help better.

Comment: Exception has occurred: TypeError
only length-1 arrays can be converted to Python scalars
  File "/Users/justinjohnson/Documents/JAVA/makeLines.py", line 36, in makeLines
    i_dRcs_Stokes.append(((112*((math.pi)**4))/15)*(((gj)*planck*c*B0*((nu0+i_dnu_Stokes)**4)*gammaSquared)/(((2*I+1)**2)*kb*T))*(i_Xj_Stokes*(math.exp(((-i_Erot)/(kb*T))))))
  File "/Users/justinjohnson/Documents/JAVA/makeLines.py", line 38, in <module>
    makeLines()

Comment: @Jake This means somewhere in your calculation, you are passing array instead of a scalar. You would need to provide us with reproducible example or print out the variables in your loop before the formula. The problem is not with appending but with your equation.

Comment: No, I want to pass in an array. I'm trying to create a new row with an array of 1x3000 values  for every loop iteration. Thus, for 30 iterations, I want to have a 30x3000 array of values.

Comment: @Jake I understand what you want. But your calculation seems to have a problem. Instead of appending, try printing it out and see if your calculations go through. If not, you need to inspect the elements in your calculation. You have not provided us with the content of those, so we cannot help further without more information. I suggest reading the link the comments provided by AMC